# Part of code not working matlab for referencing a zero cell

Tags: matlab

So with some of your help I have part of my code working, it finds the first element that is zero and puts it as a reference cell to allow me to use the data above it to calculate average peak power. However it does not allow me to use the same format for average power as it would for peak power. I am using the same data just a different function.

```
n= 1; % the following call to find retrieves only the n first element(s) found.
ref= find(data{i}(:,5)==0, n, 'first');
av_pwr(i,1)=nanmean(data {i,1}(1:ref,5));%average power in coloumn E1 in all data with reference to cell found 
peak_pwr(i,1)=nanmin(data {i,1}(1:ref,5)); %preak power in coloumn E1 in all data with reference to cell found
```

Comment: What is the error you get?
and shouldn't be nanmax if you are looking for peak power

Comment: its nanmin because the max power is actually a minus number. the error is:
Subscripted assignment dimension
mismatch.

Error in code (line 57)
    peak_pwr(i,1)=nanmin(data
    {i,1}(1:ref,5)); %preak power in
    coloumn E1 in all data with
    reference to cell found

Comment: `data {i,1}(1:ref,5)` may not contain a blank, otherwise it is interpreted as `data('{i,1}(1:ref,5)')`. What dimensions are your inputs? What dimension is ref?

Comment: the dimension is a zero, this works for av_power the calculation above this